# One more voter to delete inappropriate question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm not sure if my own question here is appropriate, but can I interest one more person in voting to delete [this closed (already deemed inappropriate) question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8091/5) from the main site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. It was somewhat offensive, off-topic, and of no value to the site, other than possibly as an example of what's off-topic.

FTR, I don't think there's anything inappropriate about this request on Meta, though Chat may have met your transient needs more transiently.

Comment: How's about I self-delete this one, and it's all good?